# Python stdout influenced by TERM setting

Tags: python, bash, terminal

For a small project I decided to give Python a go for the first time.
I got my code to work just fine but when handling the output of a python script I noticed some strange behavior.

It seems the terminal setting used influences what python's print function outputs.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print 'one two'
```

Normal output is as you would expect:

```
~/$test.py
one two
~/$
```

But if you try and get bash to read the output, it fails.
And here's how I replicate the problem:

```
~/$ set -x
~/$ ./test.py | while read V1 V2; do echo $V1; echo $V2; grep -c "$V1" /myfile; done
+ ./test.py
+ read V1 V2
+ echo 'one'
one
+ echo two
two
+ grep -c 'one' /etc/passwd
grep: Unmatched [ or [^
+ read V1 V2
~/$ set +x
```

Notice the single quotes around the 'one'?   And where is the '[' that grep complains about.
When I redirected the output to a file, and loaded it in vi, I saw some control characters in front of the output.

To fix the problem, I run the command like this:

```
~/$ (TERM=dumb; ./test.py | while read V1 V2; do echo $V1; echo $V2; grep -c "$V1" /myfile; done)
```

This works fine, but I'd really like to know why python decides it needs to format the output for a terminal.   And more importantly, how do I control this behavior?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What is `TERM` by default for you (when it behaves badly)?

Comment: You may have a bad python module loaded by default. Can you test this with a clean out of the box python install?

Comment: The python install is part of the angstrom distribution on the beagleboardblack.  I can't remember if I just installed the package for python or if it was pre-installed.

Is there a way to see what python modules are loaded by default?

Comment: The TERM was xterm-256color, fairly standard.

Comment: `python -v` prints a lot of diagnostic information to stderr.

Comment: Are you sure it is python's fault?  Can you try `./test.py | od -tx1` with and without `TERM=dumb`?